# Very long and noisy renders

Tags: rendering

I know this has been asked a lot but I really need help. I'm trying to render an interior scene, but the render time is very long. For 1500 samples in QHD resolution, the scene takes 30 minutes to render, on a GTX 1080 Ti + Intel 8700K. I tried lower resolution and fewer samples, but I just save 2-3 minutes. I also tried to optimize my scene with portals in windows and larger tiles(256x256), but it still very long. Is that normal? Also, the renders are noisy. (Also, I want to mention that my CPU and GPU are overclocked)

This render has 2000 samples in 1000x1000 resolution, it took 20 minutes to render.

[image]

Comment: Rendering takes time, what else is there to it? how long? it depends on your  computer, GPU and the complexity of your scene and the size of the final image..  If you want to render faster with a high quality consider adding more GPUs to your system or use a render farm. For a scene lime this with plain textures for the floors and walls, with no complex reflections, refractions or any kind of atmospheric effects, consider using Eevee.

Comment: Might I suggest lowering the sample count by a LOT. Around 100-200 and using the denoiser node in compositor.

Comment: Just to answer your question - Yes, this is normal :).